# Change character vector of length 1 with commas into rows and columns

Tags: r

The output of a `read.socket` "returns the string read as a length-one character vector."  I would like to split that vector into columns along the commas, then into rows along the "\n".

This is from the read.socket:

[1] "43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.435,1,43415438,43551.435,43551.50,44360547,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,4,43415437,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,1,43415435,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n

I'd like each comma to represent a column, and at "\n" to get a new row.

I've looked around so to no avail on this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a character vector of column names for the `into` argument of `separate()`...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

s <- "43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.435,1,43415438,43551.435,43551.50,44360547,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,4,43415437,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,1,43415435,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n"

tbl <- str_split(s, "\n")[[1]] %>% tibble %>%
  separate(col=1, into=as.character(1:11), sep=",")
```

Comment: if you didn't want to count the number of commas by hand you could use `num_cols <- length(unlist(gregexpr(",", s)))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic solution:

```
myData <- "43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.435,1,43415438,43551.435,43551.50,44360547,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,4,43415437,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,1,43415435,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n"

splitCol <- strsplit(myData, "\r\n")
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(splitCol[[1]])))

listCol <- c()

for (i in seq(length(splitCol[[1]]))) {
  temp <- strsplit(splitCol[[1]][i], ",")
  listCol <- c(listCol, temp)
}

df <- as.data.frame(listCol)
names(df) <- 1:length(df)
df <- t(df) # Transpose
```

Result:

```
> print(df)
  [,1]                   [,2]        [,3] [,4]       [,5]        [,6]       [,7]       [,8] [,9] [,10]
1 "43017-10-04 10:00:15" "43551.435" "1"  "43415438" "43551.435" "43551.50" "44360547" "0"  "0"  "C"  
2 "43017-10-04 10:00:15" "43551.50"  "4"  "43415437" "43551.435" "43551.50" "44360554" "0"  "0"  "C"  
3 "43017-10-04 10:00:15" "43551.50"  "1"  "43415435" "43551.435" "43551.50" "44360554" "0"  "0"  "C"
```

Comment: Thanks.  Columns and rows inverted there.  Was hoping not to loop.

Comment: I edited with the transpose function. To get rid of the loop, combine it with Benjamin Christoffersen solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution to Vicent K but more compact using `sapply`

```
> .text <- "43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.435,1,43415438,43551.435,43551.50,44360547,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,4,43415437,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,1,43415435,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n"
> 
> dt <- sapply(strsplit(.text, "\r\n")[[1]], 
+              strsplit, split = ",", USE.NAMES = FALSE)
> names(dt) <- 1:length(dt) # avoid default names
> data.frame(dt)
                     X1                   X2                   X3
1  43017-10-04 10:00:15 43017-10-04 10:00:15 43017-10-04 10:00:15
2             43551.435             43551.50             43551.50
3                     1                    4                    1
4              43415438             43415437             43415435
5             43551.435            43551.435            43551.435
6              43551.50             43551.50             43551.50
7              44360547             44360554             44360554
8                     0                    0                    0
9                     0                    0                    0
10                    C                    C                    C
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of methods. They will require some cleaning afterwards, but should get you started.

```
# read in the data
temp <- readLines(textConnection("43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.435,1,43415438,43551.435,43551.50,44360547,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,4,43415437,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n43017-10-04 10:00:15,43551.50,1,43415435,43551.435,43551.50,44360554,0,0,C,\r\n"))
```

The result here is a character vector where each element of the vector will be a row of the final object. `readLines` breaks up the input at each `\n` by default.

---

First, you can use `strsplit` to get a list of character vectors and the `rbind` them all with `do.call`.

```
# return a character matrix
do.call(rbind, strsplit(temp, ","))
```

For example, the first 5 columns

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(temp, ","))[, 1:5]
     [,1]                   [,2]        [,3] [,4]       [,5]       
[1,] "43017-10-04 10:00:15" "43551.435" "1"  "43415438" "43551.435"
[2,] "43017-10-04 10:00:15" "43551.50"  "4"  "43415437" "43551.435"
[3,] "43017-10-04 10:00:15" "43551.50"  "1"  "43415435" "43551.435"
```

To return a data.frame, just wrap these in `data.frame`.

Second, using `data.table`'s `tstrplit`, you can do

```
library(data.table)
data.frame(tstrsplit(temp, ",", names=TRUE))
```

to return a data.frame. the first 5 columns again are

```
                    V1        V2   V3       V4        V5
1 43017-10-04 10:00:15 43551.435    1 43415438 43551.435
2 43017-10-04 10:00:15  43551.50    4 43415437 43551.435
3 43017-10-04 10:00:15  43551.50    1 43415435 43551.435
4                 <NA>      <NA> <NA>     <NA>      <NA>
```

Note that the underlying vectors are of class factor, so you'll have to convert them to numeric or character or whatever.